# slide all divs when loading page jquery

Tags: jquery, html, razor

need all divs with a card class to have slideUp when the page loads

This is what I tried to do, but not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            const div = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.flex-wrap .d-flex'));
            $(div).slideUp(500);
            console.log(div);
        })
```

Html itself with a block div

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.UserTodoList)
    {
        <div class="card" style="width: 32%; margin-left: 1%; margin-top:1%">
            <div class="card-body">

                <h5 hidden class="itemName">@item.Name</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                @if (item.Body.Length > 80)
                {

                    <p hidden class="fullBody">@item.Body</p>
                    <p id="body" class="card-text">@item.Body.Substring(0, 80)...</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info buttonShow" id="1234">Прочитать</button>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p class="card-text">@item.Body</p>

                }

                <a @*asp-controller="ToDo" asp-action="DeleteTodos" asp-route-todoId="@item.Id"*@ id="buttonDelete" class="btn btn-primary btnDelete">Удалить</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: if you are using jQuery, why are you using querySelectorAll?

Comment: `d-flex` is not a child element of the top div.  It's a class on the same element.  If you are meaning to target that top div, remove the space between the selectors, just like how you would construct a CSS selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need all divs with a card class to have slideUp when the page loads

You could get all divs with card class using Jquery :

```
$(function () {

  $("div .card").each(function () {
      $(this).slideUp(5000);
  });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your implementation is that you are not applying the function `slideUp` to each element that you queried, but you are attempting to apply it to an Array of those elements.

To fix that, slightly tweak your code to be:

```
...
const div = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.flex-wrap .d-flex'));
div.forEach(el => $(el).slideUp(500));
...
```

As you can see, you had the correct intuition in grabbing all the elements when performing a `querySelectorAll` and then creating an Array. Now that you have the Array, you can quickly use the Array methods available like `forEach` and apply your jQuery functions on each item in the Array.

Comment: Standard behaviour for almost all jQuery methods, is to apply the logic to all elements in the result stack.  They perform an implicit each.  This is not the issue.

Comment: This also does not address the incorrect css selector issue, which if it is the issue, then this whole question is a typo question.